# Record answer label of the choice for randomization in Qualtrics using javascript

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

I am designing a survey in Qualtrics. each question has multiple choice answers, 5 fixed and 8 random, the 5 multiple choices will be constant and render all the time. I'll throw only one choice out of the 8 randomize choices to be presented with the 5 constant choices, so total multiple choices will be render is 6. Finally I need to capture in the embedded data field which choice of the 8 random was associated with the 5 fixed choices. I found this code and it works perfect But so far its capturing the IDs of the choices. however, I need to capture the label name of the item instead of the IDs.

```js
//get the div containing the choices, then get all input child elements of that div
var choices = this.getChoiceContainer().getElementsByTagName("input");
//initialize an array for the IDs of the choices
var choiceIDs = []
//add the ID of each choice to the array
for (var i=0; i < choices.length; i++) {
 choiceIDs.push(choices[i].id);
  
}
//get the current choice order from embedded data and add this loop to it.
//Add a | to distinguish between loops.
var choiceOrder = "${e://field/choiceorder}" + choiceIDs.toString() + "|";
//set the embedded data with the new value
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData("choiceorder", choiceOrder);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need JavaScript for this.  You can just pipe the displayed choices into an embedded variable in the survey flow:

```
choiceorder = ${q://QIDxx/ChoiceGroup/DisplayedChoices}
```

Comment: So far it didn't work for my case, however, I tested your solution for different case and it works fine for the case of All choices-Displayed & Hidden. but the logic of my survey is I have 5 fixed display and 8 hidden choices. in the set up advanced randomization I only mapped the 8 choices to the (Random Subset field) then Randomly insert 1 choice from those 8 hidden choices with the other 5 fixed displayed choices. Finally I have the 5 fixed display choices with {1 Random Subset}. Which make it a total of 6 multiple choices displayed to the users.

Comment: I understand what you did. It works fine for me, so I think you've done something wrong: https://marketinview.qualtrics.com/jfe/preview/SV_9N9aUsktdodXhiZ?Q_CHL=preview

Comment: This is the steps:- Survey Flow -> Add a new field -> choiceorder-> Set a value Now -> Insert Piped Text -> Survey Question->QID ->Displayed Choices

Comment: Yes this works fine for the case of one specific question, But in my survey I have 2 Block and each black has more than 5 questions and I'm presenting only one of them randomly. How can I achieve the same concept for a black with multiple questions? 

Do I have to create individual embedded data for each question or is there is a way to make it generic (e.g. one embedded data for the entire block) ?